# Accessing all variables passed to a shell script from a given index

Tags: shell

How can I access the values within `$@` starting from the third one? Right now I'm passing them from three to nine, but I think theres a better way:

```
while getopts ":n" opt "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"; do
```

Comment: The way you're currently doing it right now looks fine.

Comment: I'd use `shift 2` and leave off the args after "opt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a funky approach to arguments to me, but:

```
[kbrandt@kbrandt: ~/scrap] cat args
args=("$@")
echo ${args[0]}
echo ${args[@]:1:2}
echo ${args[@]:0:$#}
[kbrandt@kbrandt: ~/scrap] bash args foo bar baz biz
foo
bar baz
foo bar baz biz
```

I recommend you check out the [FAQ Answer](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) about command line arguments (Which basically says getopts or loop/case/shift).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there some sort of sub-array syntax, from 3 to max? Even from 3 to 9 would be enough for my needs.

Comment: Updated accordingly (slice of array), not to sure about what the compatibility / portability of those slices is.

Comment: Might be funky , indeed. I'm using it to force the first two arguments to always be fixed, and then the order of the rest is not enforced.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using bash in this instance?

If so, you should use [shift](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html).

An example:

Contents of shift.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
shift 3
echo $*
```

Result:

```
graeme@graeme:~$ ./shift.sh one two three four five six
four five six
```